# Android drawing marker dynamically in bradcast receiver

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

I am sending latitude and longitude I received from my server and passing them to broadcastreceiver to draw a marker and update it's location continuously based on the updates it receives from the server. The location updates are coming from another device and I am tracking that device and display it's location in my app as follows:

```
@Override
        public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
            if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            String lati = data.getString("lati");
            String longi = data.getString("longi");
                Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                mIntent.putExtra(LOCATION, lati + "," + longi);
                mIntent.setAction(UPDATE_COORDINATES); //should match the receiver intent filter at the registering
                coordintesupdater.sendBroadcast(mIntent);
            } else {
                Log.i("Received", "empty message");
            }
        }
```

This is my broadcast receiver that is not being called nor does it receive the latitude and longitude.

```
private BroadcastReceiver locationupdatesreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String messagestr = intent.getStringExtra(MyGcmListenerService.UPDATE_COORDINATES);
            String latst = "", lonst = "";
            double lati, longi;
            if (messagestr != null && !messagestr.isEmpty()) {
                String[] separated = messagestr.split(",");
                latst = separated[0].trim();
                lonst = separated[1].trim();
                try {
                    lati = Double.parseDouble(separated[0].trim());
                    longi = Double.parseDouble(separated[1].trim());
                    //cLocation.setLatitude(lati);
                    //cLocation.setLongitude(longi);
                    LatLng updatedloc = new LatLng(lati, longi);
                    //draw the cab and update it's location periodically
                    drawLocationUpdatesonMap(updatedloc);
                }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                    nfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void drawLocationUpdatesonMap(final LatLng newlocatioin){
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener mLoChangeListnener = new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                //if (cMarker != null)
                //   cMarker.remove();
        Log.i("device location", newlocatioin.toString());
                cabMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(newlocatioin)
                        .visible(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mmovingc))
                        .flat(true));
            }
        };
        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(mLoChangeListnener);
    }
```

FYI the GcmListenerservice is a nested class of my map activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's so embarrassing. I forgot to register and unregister the broadcastreceiver in OnResume and Onpause respectively. It now works like a charm.